# Android package organization

Tags: java, android

I am fairly new to Android development, so I have some questions about Android project/code design.

1. Do people generally split up API calls into a separate class/classes? Or do you call them within the object itself?
2. Are packages just sub-directories? From what I understand, they're only used for the benefit of the programmer as an organizational tool.

I know that these questions are somewhat subjective, but I'm interested in how other developers organize their code. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ad packages organization - I develop applications for Android about two years and I have organized source similarly as Andrea Cinesi wrote. But this week I started thinking if it would be more appropriate to package was as application module, for example:

```
com.example.android
.car
  CarActivity
  CarListFragment
  CarDetailFragment
  CarListAdapter
  ...
.route
  RouteActivity
  RouteListFragment
  RouteDetailFragment
  RouteListAdapter
  ...
.utils
.services
etc.
```

I'm not yet thinkin twice what all shoul be in "module" (e.g. data entity). But why I'm thinking about this changing? Because in middle or large projects are very much activities / fragments / etc. in one package - and this is confusing to me - I see it especially for larger projects acquired from other developers.

And one more advantage can be divided into module packages - java package-private visibility of methods.

I am not yet decided whether to use this or that variant, but I think for smaller projects do not care and for middle or big project it may be preferable option packages as modules.